# Failing to start autoware auto on NVidia Jetson Xavier

Tags: ros2, ros-melodic, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the installation instructions for Autoware.auto found in this link: https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/installation-and-development.html
but I am encountering an error when I run `ade start`. My terminal shows

```
nvidia@matt-xavier:~/m2/adehome/AutowareAuto$ ade start
Starting ade with the following images:
ade          | n/a     | master | registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/ade:master
ade-atom     | v1.39.1 | latest | registry.gitlab.com/apexai/ade-atom:latest                                  
autowareauto | n/a     | master | registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto:master    
ade_registry.gitlab.com_apexai_ade-atom_latest
ade_registry.gitlab.com_autowarefoundation_autoware.auto_autowareauto_master
non-network local connections being added to access control list
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
ERROR: Failed to start ade. Re-run with --debug to get more information.
```

Of course when I run `ade --debug`, I get `Error: no such option: --debug`. How do I resolve this problem?

I am using a NVidia Jetson AGX Xavier flashed with JetPack 4.2.2 (so Ubuntu 18.04 bionic). I did not explicitly install any version of ROS 2, since I assumed that was part of the docker image in ADE (and no part of the installation instructions told me to explicitly install ROS 2). I have ROS melodic installed, if that's relevant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339008/failing-to-start-autoware-auto-on-nvidia-jetson-xavier/) by [blarghflargle](https://answers.ros.org/users/49943/blarghflargle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@blarghflargle that looks like a compatibility issue with the ade image, since your board is Arm based and looks like the ade image is compiled for amd64 architectures. You can try building it natively

---

Originally posted by [sgermanserrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/41059/sgermanserrano/) with karma: 166 on 2019-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blarghflargle](https://answers.ros.org/users/49943/blarghflargle/) on 2019-12-03**:
Thank you for your response! How did you find that the ade image is compiled for amd64? And how do I build it natively?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-12-03**:
This is correct. The Docker containers for `ade` are currently not compiled natively for `arm64`, only for `amd64` which means they can not be run on an ARM-based processor like the Jetson.

**Comment by [blarghflargle](https://answers.ros.org/users/49943/blarghflargle/) on 2019-12-03**:
@sgermanserrano @Maximus5684 How would I go about building the docker image for ARMv8?

**Comment by [sgermanserrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/41059/sgermanserrano/) on 2019-12-04**:
@blarghflargle you'll need to put together a Dockerfile based on ROS Dashing and Melodic, since .auto depends on the ros1_bridge, clone the .auto repo and colcon build it. Or, you can pull [this](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/96boards/autoware) .auto docker image I put together to use in 96Boards hardware which is also arm64 based

**Comment by [blarghflargle](https://answers.ros.org/users/49943/blarghflargle/) on 2019-12-06**:
thanks @sgermanserrano ! How do I actually make use of the .auto docker image you put together? do I put `registry.hub.docker.com/96boards/autoware:auto` in the .aderc?

**Comment by [sgermanserrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/41059/sgermanserrano/) on 2019-12-09**:
@blarghflargle you should be able to follow the steps [here](https://www.96boards.org/blog/autoware.auto_hikey970/) for your hardware

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this post is a little old but I wanted to provide an update that `arm64`-native ADE images are now available! On Jetson Xavier (or other native `arm64` platforms), all you should have to do to test them is source the `.aderc-arm64` file in the root of the AutowareAuto repo before running `ade start`.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-06-18**:
Clarification: Nvidia Jetson is not an officially supported platform at this time. The `arm64` images "should" work but are not guaranteed to work on Nvidia Jetson.